# Invalid Signature OVH' s SMS

Tags: c#, api, sms, ovh

I am trying to send SMS using OVH'SMS service , following [this docs](https://docs.ovh.com/fr/sms/envoyer_des_sms_avec_lapi_ovh_en_c/).

when i test the send with post methode for the url https://eu.api.ovh.com/1.0/sms/sms-zj16668-1/jobs

i get an

> errorCode:INVALID_SIGNATURE

the signature is calculated as below :

```
        String signature = "$1$" + HashSHA1(AS + "+" + CK + "+" + METHOD + "+" + QUERY + "+" + BODY + "+" + TSTAMP);
```

with Get method(no Body) i get a successful result , however when i change to use a Post method with a Body ,the above error is triggered.

this is the Body i pass to signature :

```
        string BODY = @"{  ""receivers"": [ ""+33601020304"" ], ""message"": ""Test SMS OVH"", ""senderForResponse"": true}";
```

what i m doing wrong ?

## update

i found in the ovh community a similar  [issue](http://community.ovh.com/t/envoi-de-sms-via-c-ne-fonctionne-plus/22655/22) and the solution where to use TLS1.2 PROTOCOL , however even after adding this proposed line of code:

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

I am still getting the same error ! ?

Comment: If you're still having issues with this, you should probably provide more code for how you're sending the request.

Comment: the code is the c# code in the docs specified above in the question